# Using a JScrollPane

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

My program needs to be able to display data on screen for an unknown number of objects.

I am using Netbeans GUI creator but i have no idea of how to have the data for these objects displayed inside the `JScrollPane`

Answer (score 3):

You're question is vague.  You don't provide any information about "how" you might like to display these objects.

Start by having a read through [How to use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html).

You should also have a look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) and [How to use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), which provide different ways of showing data.

Basically, you need to supply a "view" to the scroll.  This would be you base component, onto which other components would be added.